# how to create custom info window for clustered marker and single marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am using android map utility library to create cluster marker and now i want to open a custom window for clustered marker and single marker.

There are lots of questions available on stack overflow but none of them told how to open and hide window for particular marker.
i have followed this question but it didn't get helpful in my case

How to show all name of clustered marker in a list in custom window.

Comment: Have you used `setOnMarkerClickListener` for `Marker`?

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have used this library [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/)   to create clustered marker and used its own on marker click listener.

Comment: there are `getClusterMarkerCollection()` and `getMarkerCollection()` methods in [ClusterManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) class,  you can use them to retrieve the marker of cluster collection, and how the name of your clusters, when the `setOnClusterClickListener` is called.

Comment: @ztan yes bu tell me how open a info window inside that method..because i cant get any method there to open the window

Comment: Please help me regarding this its very important.

Comment: @ztan where to put showinfowindow() method to open a custom info window using [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) over clustered marker and clustered item marker.